# Need to update a field in case based on certain conditions in child object

Tags: trigger, class, before-trigger, after-trigger

I'm trying to update a field called **Survey Sent field** on case object. But before this update that there are certain fields on the child object, which impacts on update on survey sent on case object. I could able populate the close date in survey sent field upon on closing the case but when I move the status from Closed to Not Closed [Working, wtv] the **Survey sent field** is not showing as blank. Which It should. I need help on this please.

```
public static void Sendnotification(List<Case> NewCseLst){
     Try {
     set<Id> contactidset = new set<id>();
     List<Id> caseids = new List<Id>();

     for(Case cse: NewCseLst)
     {
        caseids.add(cse.id);
     }

     List<Licensee__c> LstLcnsee = [select id,User__c,User__r.email,AMSStart__c, AMSEnd__c, No_Support__c, User__r.Nb_Days_since_last_survey__c, User__r.HasOptedOutOfEmail, Support_Status__c, SN__r.Banned__c, SN__r.Block_Support__c, SN__r.Bad_Debt__c from Licensee__c where User__c in:contactidset];

     for(Case cs : NewCseLst)
     {
     if(cs.Product__c != 'Certification' && cs.AccountId != '00130000007Z0nL' && cs.Age_days__c <= 30 && cs.Survey_Type__c == 'Agent' && cs.Problem_Type__c != 'Sales/Trial Request' && cs.Parentid == null ) {
     if(LstLcnsee !=null && LstLcnsee.size()>0) {
     for(LIcensee__c LIC: LstLcnsee)
     {
     if(LIC.No_Support__c == false && LIC.SN__r.Banned__c == false && LIC.AMSEnd__c > System.TODAY() && LIC.SN__r.Block_Support__c == false && LIC.SN__r.Bad_Debt__c == false && (LIC.User__r.Nb_Days_since_last_survey__c > 30 || LIC.User__r.Nb_Days_since_last_survey__c == 0)  &&  LIC.User__r.HasOptedOutOfEmail == false) {
                    //ContactEmailIDSet.add(User__r.email);

                    If(cs.Status == 'Closed') {
                    cs.simplesurvey__Survey_Sent__c = cs.ClosedDate;

                } else {
                cs.simplesurvey__Survey_Sent__c= null;
                }
}
}
}
}
}
}
catch(Exception ex)
{
System.debug('Exception:'+ex.getMessage());
}
}
```

Comment: aside from a) the indenting, b) the hard-coded accountId - is there a relationship between `Licensee__c` and `Case` -- is there a lookup field from Licensee__c to Case (like `Case__c`)?  I suspect this handler class could be so much simpler

Comment: @cropredy there is no direct relationship between Licensee__c and Case objects. They both are indirectly related by CONTACTS object. Licensee__c have lookup relation with Contact.

Answer (score 0):

Have you debug it? The list - contactidset - will always be empty, as you are not populating it, therefore you won't receive any record when querying Licensee__C object